# Intel Desktop Board DH67CL

Tags: motherboard, hardware-raid

I have purchased a system with Intel DH67CL Board, which offers RAID Support of 0,1,10 levels.

I want to install Windows 2008R2 on it but first want to create a RAID 1 or RAID 10 (I have 4 Sata HDDs attached internally to this machine) with 16GB RAM.

I can't seem to find an option in its BIOS or don't see a prompt when it boots to get into the Raid Utility - any ideas or suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you first need to enable Intel RAID in the BIOS, and then enter the RAID setup by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> during POST.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have gone through the BIOS and can't seem to find the option to enable raid anywhere - however the board does support raid. any thoughts ? Also any suggestions for the NIC to work oN Windows 2008R2